# Hiding cursor in console window

Tags: java, cursor, console-application

In Java, how can I hide the cursor in a console/terminal window in a cross-platform way (Windows, Mac and Linux)?

Needless to say, this is about the text cursor not the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that easy for any Plattform. But you can use something like lanterna:

https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna